# Linux (Fedora) Cannot run psql command in terminal - role does not exist

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, psql, pg-hba.conf

I have seen all the questions here on stackoverflow about similar topic, but I would like to know why this happens, where is the problem, and what to do to set it up correctly. I am learning to code, so I apologize for any misunderstandings. Please, have patience with me.

My case is -

I cannot run `psql` command from terminal.

Respond is -

```
psql: FATAL:  role "some_name" does not exist
```

after I write down and hit enter -

`sudo -u postgres -i`

everything just works and I can run `psql` command. I need to write `sudo -u postgres -i` command every time I open terminal, again and again.

I would like to kindly thanks to any respond.

If you got more questions I can give you more information.

Here see some additional info:

```
[postgres@localhost ~]$ psql
psql (9.6.6)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member
 of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------
----
 matus     |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Another:

```
[postgres@localhost ~]$ whoami
postgres
```

So, I have two opened terminals, one as `postgres` and another as `user_name` where I can do other stuff, using db somehow.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your description I suppose you have peer authentication in hba file. To check it connect to db with psql (your `sudo -u postgres` method) and:

```
t=# show hba_file ;
      hba_file
---------------------
 /pg/d10/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
t=# \! grep local /pg/d10/pg_hba.conf | grep -v "#"
local   all             all                                     peer
```

if you see peer above trust, or just peer, than this is the case. from manuals:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER

> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   **operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name** (with optional user name mapping)

formatting mine.

so in order to avoid

> psql: FATAL:  role "some_name" does not exist

just create such db user:

```
create user some_name;
```

or change `peer` to `trust` in `hba.conf`

Comment: thank you very much, I have changed authentication to `trust`, but the other problem was that i created user/role manually in postgres, and it was not the same name as default user name in the OS, so I used `ALTER USER user RENAME TO new_name_of_user;` to have name of user in postgres the same as default in the OS, and than grant him some `PRIVILEGES`.